# How can I diagnose a software "stuck" mouse button?

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, mouse, debugging, touchpad

I'm running arch on a Lenovo X1 Carbon. I can go about using it mornally, usually for a day or two but at some point my mouse buttons become "stuck" in the software (though I suppose it could be a hardware problem).

By "stuck" I mean the mouse still moves with input on the touchpad, but if I'm on a webpage it will highlight the text when I move the mouse as if I'm holding the selct button down. The keyboard seems to work normally, allowing me to `Esc` to break the select but moving reengages it.

Rebooting the device always solves the problem for some time.

At this point I'd just like to know what I can do to eliminate sources of the problem. So far I have tried:

- Looking in `journalctl` nothing looks interesting or related to input
- Adjusting mouse settings while experiencing the problem to try to "reset" it
- Confirmed I'm using `libinput` which seems to be the correct library for my touchpad

NOTE: It happened again as I typed this out, gah

Edit: I was able to recover the current "stuck" button by removing `psmouse` and `mousedev` though I'm not sure how my mouse is working now

Edit2: Using `xinput` I was able to find a device with buttons down :

`xinput list` showed my devices including:

```
↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]`
```

`xinput query-state TPPS/2\ Elan\ TrackPoint` showed two down buttons

`xinput disable 14` unstuck the button.

I still don't know what is going wrong but at least I can fix it

Comment: `xinput query-state <your pointing device id>`